# How can I conditionally map multiple arrays with if statements after fetching an array of objects? (React)

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-hooks, state

This is all in Prescriptions.js

I am fetching a bunch of prescription drugs from my api.

```js
const [drugs, setDrugs] = React.useState([]);
    
useEffect(() => {
    fetch('/api/drugs')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(json => setDrugs(json))
}, [drugs])
```

After that's done, I want to make a category array based on drug.class and render it down there. If that category already exists, then push the drug into it's category's array, if it doesn't, make a new array based on that category, push the drug into that array, and render it as shown.

```js
</Select>
    <ListSubheader>Category 1</ListSubheader>
    <MenuItem value="valuehere">Option 1</MenuItem>
    <MenuItem value="valuehere">Option 2</MenuItem>
    <ListSubheader>Category 2</ListSubheader>
    <MenuItem value="valuehere">Option 3</MenuItem>
    <MenuItem value="valuehere">Option 4</MenuItem>
</Select>
```

I've been trying to get this done for days and I am stuck, would appreciate some help!

Comment: you used `drugs` as a dependency, and inside that useEffect, you are updating the drags by setDrugs, this is not a good practice. remove `drugs` if you want to fetch only once.

Comment: ````</Select>```` ==> ````<Select>````. How about nesting to Array.map() functions, one for category and inside it one for drugs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
return categories.map(category => (
  <> 
    <ListSubheader>{category.name}</ListSubheader>
    {drugs.map(drug => drug.category === category.name ? 
      <MenuItem value={drug.value}>{drug.name}</MenuItem>
      : null
    )}
  </>
))
```

Comment: I've had to use curly braces { } since I'm using it in an already made component and not return. This seems to work, however, I'm getting a different error in result of this code due to Material-UI. "index.js:1 Material-UI: The Menu component doesn't accept a Fragment as a child.
Consider providing an array instead."

Comment: hmm so does the error still show when you replace ````<>```` and ````</>```` with a e.g. a ````<div>````? Also remember to provide keys on MenuItem and ListSubHeader

Comment: I have provided MenuItem with d._id and ListSubHeader with a c.id that I've hardcoded on the category array. I've replaced <> and </> with a span, however, when I click on one of the drugs in the dropdown, the label value does not update. Error: You have provided an out-of-range value `undefined` for the select component.
Consider providing a value that matches one of the available options or ''.
The available values are `4`, `5`, `6`.

Comment: Also this: index.js:1 Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop. However, I've assigned a key.

Comment: I recommend using React Developer Tools for Chrome so that you can inspect your components and see their acutal keys. This debugging the key error you are getting. Also if the order of the items will never change after render it's okay to use array indexes as keys. Also React Developer Tools allows you to see what exactly is placed in the value that it is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

You want to parse your API's response to a structure that you can easily iterate over, and render UI elements for. How to do this *exactly*, depends on the structure of your response. `lodash` is very useful for this purpose.

Ie.:

```js
import _ from 'lodash'

const [drugs, setDrugs] = useState([])    
useEffect(() => {
    fetch('/api/drugs')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(json => {
            // assume `json` now has the structure:
            // [{ class: 'fooClass', name: 'bar'}, { ... }]
            setDrugs(_.groupBy(json, 'class'))
            // `drugs` now has the structure:
            // { fooClass: [{...}] }
        })
}, [drugs])

// now we can iterate over the parsed groups:
return (
    <div>
        {_.map(drugs, (drugs, category) =>
            <div>
                <ListSubheader>{category}</ListSubheader>
                {_.map(drugs, drug => <MenuItem>{drug.name}</MenuItem>)}
            </div>
        )}
    </div>
)
```